# Writing points to a file

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, geometry, cursor

Trying to write the city name and point coords to a file. The following works with a polygon shapefile but not the point shapefile. I know I'm missing something basic.

```
import arcpy

# Set up the Environment
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\temp"

fc = r"C:\Utemp\cities.shp"
fields = ['SHAPE@XY']
output = open(r"C:\temp\cities.txt", 'w')
COFilePath = r"C:\temp\cities.csv"
COFile = open (COFilePath, "w")

# For each row write citiy name & coords
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, "SHAPE@")
for row in cursor:
    for point in row[0].getPart(0):
        COFile.write(str(point.X) + ", " + str(point.Y) + "\n")
COFile.close()
```

> Error: TypeError: 'Point' object is not iterable

Comment: Looks something like row[0].getPart(0) already returns a Point but you are trying to access it as an array of points.

Comment: Little debug tip:
Throw the code into arcmaps python window, run it and inspect the last value of row (should be the first though). Use type(row) and type type(row[0]) for example.

Comment: @Andreas - Very new to python. row = type(row[0]) = <class 'arcpy.arcobjects.geometries.PointGeometry'>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`row.getPart(0)` is necessarily returning the first geometry in the row, so it won't be an iterable.

Thus your code becomes:

```
import arcpy

# Set up the Environment
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\temp"

fc = r"C:\Utemp\cities.shp"
fields = ['SHAPE@XY']
output = open(r"C:\temp\cities.txt", 'w')
COFilePath = r"C:\temp\cities.csv"
COFile = open (COFilePath, "w")

# For each row write citiy name & coords
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, "SHAPE@")
for row in cursor:
    point = row[0].getPart(0)
    COFile.write(str(point.X) + ", " + str(point.Y) + "\n")

COFile.close()
```

Though I would recommend using `with` blocks in this case to avoid leaving things (cursors, files) open in case of an error. Also note that you open a file that you never use, and you don't close it, so I've cleaned that up.

```
import arcpy

# Set up the Environment
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\temp"

fc = r"C:\Utemp\cities.shp"
fields = ['SHAPE@XY']
output = open(r"C:\temp\cities.txt", 'w')

with open(r"C:\temp\cities.csv", 'w') as COFile:
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, "SHAPE@") as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            point = row[0].getPart(0)
            COFile.write("{}, {}\n".format(point.X, point.Y))
```

Note: the `getPart(0)` might not be necessary. `point = row[0]` *may* suffice.

So what's going on here? A cursor is a object that iterates through the shapefile only once (typically called a "generator", but arcpy is weird so I don't know if that's strictly true). So the `for row in cursor` line is conceptually the same as walking down the attribute table. Within each row, you're selecting the first column with `row[0]`, which is the geometry in this case. Generally speaking, geometries can have multiple parts (e.g., boundaries that are attached to the mainland, but also have islands), but you're only looking an the first part with `row[0].getPart(0)`, which returns a `point` geometry. Then you're writing the x- and y-coords to a file.

Comment: Thank you so much, not only for the code, but the explanation. The only difference I see is that you use with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, "SHAPE@") as cursor: and I used cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, "SHAPE@"). Not sure how those are different other than format. Try to understand.

Comment: @KenKirkeby yes that's the only difference between my two solutions. The main difference between my solutions and your code is that I'm not trying to loop the result of `row[0].getPart(0)`

Comment: @KenKirkeby I also just demonstrated a different string formatting method, in case you're curious.